# How to use jQuery .each() in PHP foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `foreach` loop with an array of images and a JS code to add a different classes whether the width is greater than its height and vice versa.

The problem is that the `if` function get the `.width()` and `.height()` values of the first images in the array and add the same class to all the images that follows.

I try to use `.each()` and when I print `console.log()` it gives the value of the first image, recognize that there are more but not add them the spesific class.

HTML:

```html
<?php foreach ( $feedback as $feed ): ?>
  <img class="img" src="<?php echo $feed['pic']; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
  $feedback = [
    [
      'pic' => '1.jpg',
    ],
    [
      'pic' => '1.jpg',
    ],
    [
      'pic' => '1.jpg',
    ],
    [
      'pic' => '1.jpg',
    ],
  ]
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('.img');
  var img_w = img.width();
  var img_h = img.height();
  img.each(function() {
    if ( img_w > img_h ) {
      $(this).addClass('port');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('land');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `var img_w = img.width(); var img_h = img.height();` gives you the dimensions of the first image maybe? you'll probably want to do that inside the loop to get per image dimensions using `$(this).width()` etc before the `if`

Comment: You need to get the images width and heigh inside `img.each` loop to get them per image

Comment: [`.width()` - _"Get the current computed width for the **first element** in the set of matched elements."_](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width1)

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the first image's width/height because they are outside of the function. You need to get the width/height from each image, so you need to put it inside of the foreach loop.
Also, it's more efficient to not make it into a variable since you're only using the width and height once per image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('.img');

  img.each(function() {
    if ( $(this).width() > $(this).height() ) {
      $(this).addClass('port');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('land');
    }
  });
});
```